# Odd "can not resolve" issue

Tags: android, import, resolve

I am not sure what is happening and how to resolve this issue...

I am using a Toolbar and other items using various imports on Android Studio (see screen shot below).

[The imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn731.jpg)

The code is working perfectly apart from:

1. The imports appear in red (as on the screenshot)
2. Error is highlighted through out as per this screenshot: [Errors...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLuwV.jpg)

However, when I run this code on my emulator or my phone, it runs perfectly!

Why?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to sync project with gradle files.
If the lines still appear in red, Android studio is marking the imports that are available in SDK version higher than the one you have chosen as minimum for your project.

Comment: Unfortunately no success despite syncing and increasing the minSdkVersion to the maximum available of 27.

Comment: Did you also try invalidate caches and restart?